Jquery Range Slider Show and Hide Div
I am Trying to Show() and Hide() Divs but this way only works going forward and not backwards.
I'm trying to Change the Div with the range Slider and HIDE any other Div. I tried ui.value minus 1 Hide() but it doesn't work.
So my Question is How to Change a DIV with a Range Slider Forward and Backwards?


$(function() {
  $("#slider1").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".div" + ui.value).show();
      $(".div" + ui.value - 1).hide();
    }
  });
});
body {
  background-color: #6A6A6A;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#slider1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 1%;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 175px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-horizontal {
  height: .6em;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 10vh !important;
  cursor: default;
}

.div1,
.div2,
.div3,
.div4,
.div5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: #16168f;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: #268226;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: #ffbb00;
}

.div4 {
  background-color: #565656;
}

.div5 {
  background-color: #66668f;
}
<div class="box">
  <div id="slider1"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="div5"></div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tim-school.com/codepen/jquery-slider/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>




@Timbukto :-
With minor change in your code, you can easily achieve your expected result:
Add a common class to your html DIVs as shown below:
<div class="box">
    <div id="slider1"></div>
    <div class="slider_div div1"></div>
    <div class="slider_div  div2"></div>
    <div class="slider_div div3"></div>
    <div class="slider_div div4"></div>
    <div class="slider_div div5"></div>
</div>

and now change the js script as shown below:
       $("#slider1").slider({
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            value: 0,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $(".slider_div").hide();   // it will hide any of the active div
                $(".div" + ui.value).show();
                
            }
        });

So, for JS script, first hide the active/displayed div and then show the div which is needed to show.

I found a little issue in your jQuery function. You need to select all divs at the same time and hide them first. I will provide sample code.


$(function () {
    $("#slider1").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        value: 0,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            // Select all divs and hide them first.
            $(".slider_item").hide();
                    
            // Show the div corresponding to the current slider value
            $(".div" + ui.value).show();
        }
    });
});
body {
    background-color: #6A6A6A;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#slider1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 1%;
    height: 6vh;
    width: 175px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: .6em;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 25px !important;
    height: 10vh !important;
    cursor: default;
}

.div1,
.div2,
.div3,
.div4,
.div5 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
}

.div1 {
    background-color: #16168f;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: #268226;
}

.div3 {
    background-color: #ffbb00;
}

.div4 {
    background-color: #565656;
}

.div5 {
    background-color: #66668f;
}
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://tim-school.com/codepen/jquery-slider/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <div id="slider1"></div>
            <div class="slider_item div1"></div>
            <div class="slider_item div2"></div>
            <div class="slider_item div3"></div>
            <div class="slider_item div4"></div>
            <div class="slider_item div5"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>




This way works ..But i have over 2500 divs on my page.

Hi, @Timbukto, I understood. In this case, you can make a shared class name and then use the class name to select all div elements. I just updated my answer. Hope it helps you.

jQuery Does the Heavy Lifting
When dealing with multiple elements, jQuery makes it so simple sometimes you might forget that you can group specific <div>s and isolate them by:

using the many jQuery methods which can be chained into powerful combos or by...

using special jQuery selector extensions or by...

using a substring matching attribute selector.


Let's look at the following example:
Problematic HTML Layout ⁉️
<!--
  Access to div.div1, div.div2, div.div3, div.div4, and div.div5 
  is needed but not div#slider1. 
  #slider1 should be separated from those `<div>` for functional, 
  heirarcharial, and semantical reasons.           
-->
<div class="box">
  <div id="slider1"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="div5"></div>
</div>

We'll quickly go through some solutions and see why they're not optimal. First off you need to deal with those <div>s as a group then use loops, recursion, conditions, delegation, etc to whittle them down to the actual <div>(s) that need to be processed. Here's some ways that you should avoid:
Do Not Do the Following 
// Select each class because they differ by a single character
$(".div1, .div2, .div3, .div4, .div5")

// Select by the tagName but you'll get #slider1 as well
$(".box div")

// If you don't mind a convoluted selector use :not()
$("div:not(#slider1)")

The example below deals with the bad layout using the three recommendations previously listed.

Use jQuery methods.
/*
  Get all <div>s inside .box then select the second <div> 
  (index 1) and all proceeding <div>s will be gathered into a 
  new jQuery collection. Index 0 was skipped which is #slider1.
*/
$(".box div").slice(1);

// Get all <div>s within .box that are not #slider1.
$(".box div").not("#slider1");

/*
  Get all <div>s that are descendants of .box and have any 
  className.
*/
$(".box div").filter([class]);


Use jQuery extensions.
// Anything in .box that does NOT have an id that equals slider1.
$(".box [id!='slider1']")

// Any element in .box with the style display: none
$(".box :hidden")

/*
  Any descendant of .box that has no children nodes. Nodes 
  in this context are elements and text. #slider1 is initially 
  empty but jQuery UI adds several `<div>`s in it as a 
  requirement of the .slider() widget.
*/
$(".box :empty")


Using a substring matching attribute selector. These selectors have been around before I even started programming and jQuery is not required.
/*
  This selector declares: "Get any element in .box that has a 
  className that starts with the word: "div"
*/
$(".box [class^='div']")

/* 
  This selector is little less accurate declaring: "Get any 
  element in .box that has a className that contains the 
  word: "div".
*/
$(".box [class*='div']")



In the following demo the HTML layout has been arranged so that #slider is outside of area where it can be a hinderance. .box is a <menu> and it has 5 <li> instead of 5 dull <div>s. Also,  the HTML is a complete page. Note the placement of the <link> and <script> tags is optimal. Moreover, the JS and CSS files are up to date and from the same CDN. One more thing, there are 2 CSS files for jQuery UI and I noticed your post only had one and it appeared that the slider styles were incomplete. There are details commented in the demo.


$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: 6,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      // Gather all <li> of <menu> into a jQuery object.
      const $items = $("menu li");
      /*
        Pass the current value (number) to the $.eq() method 
        which locates the specific element found by the given 
        index number.
      */
      const $li = $items.eq(ui.value);
      /* 
        Find any <li> that are ":visible" which is basically 
        anything but display: none
      */
      const $old = $items.filter(":visible");
      // If a ":visible" <li> is found, fade it out...
      if ($old) $old.fadeOut();
      /*
        finally, fade in the <li> positioned at the index number 
        that matches the slider's current value.
      */
      $li.fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
body {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #6A6A6A;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  min-width: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vw;
}

li:first-child {
  background-color: #16168f;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #268226;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #ffbb00;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #565656;
}

li:last-child {
  background-color: #BADDAD;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 70vw;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.1/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.1/themes/dark-hive/theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <main>
    <div id="slider"></div>
    <menu>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </menu>
  </main>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.14.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



